# Merging two tables without any join key

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I'm currently having some difficulties when trying to merge two tables.

Example:

Table_1:

```
Sylvester
Kim
Charlotte
Jessica
Theodor
```

Table_2:

```
01-01-2014
02-01-2014
03-01-2014
etc..
```

Every name from table_1, needs to be merge with every date in table_2.

Outcome:

Table_3(name, date):

```
Sylvester, 01-01-2014
Sylvester, 02-01-2014
Sylvester, 03-01-2014
Charlotte, 01-01-2014
Charlotte, 02-01-2014
Charlotte, 03-01-2014
and etc...
```

I've tried to make a merge statement, but couldn't get it to Work.
Does any of you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `cross join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table_1 t1 cross join
     table_2 t2;
```

If you really need these in another table, put `create table table_3 as` before the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * INTO Table_3 FROM Table_1, Table_2
```

The comma is technically a join to it may not work for your purpose, but it will select every combination of records from Table_1 and Table_2 and insert them into Table_3

Edit: T-SQL solution not Oracle. Sorry about that

Comment: `INTO` has a different meaning in Oracle.  You use it to assign variables in PL/SQL.

Comment: Ouch. Thanks. I guess I have been out of the Oracle game too long.